# navbar toggle is not working when providing proper dependencies in angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to work on Navbar with collapse menu and dropdown link using Bootstrap 4 and Angular 6 but somehow Navbar is not working at all. I can see elements correctly but they don't function as intended.

I installed Bootstrap via Angular CLI using 'ng install bootstrap' and Bootstrap dependencies: `ng install jquery` and `ng install popper.js`

I also included Bootstrap, jquery and popper.js in package.json and angular.json

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mean-course",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "start:server": "nodemon ./backend/server.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.5",
    "angular-jwt": "^0.1.11",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "bcrypt": "^2.0.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "helmet": "^3.21.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.0.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.12",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.4",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "mean-course": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "Backend/dist/",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "./node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "mean-course:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "mean-course:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "mean-course:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "./node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "mean-course:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "mean-course:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "mean-course"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the base Bootstrap that uses jQuery. This version does not play well with Angular and breaks standard practices.

Fortunately, there is a great package that replicates all Bootstrap events in Angular like Modals, menus, dropdowns, and more.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

The installation instructions are straightforward. You'll import the css from the Bootstrap package like you normally do but you import the components into your module.

Comment: @austunthedeveloper i already worked on application and application is too large....how can i easy mange it.....with ng-bootstrap ithink there will be alot of changes to do? i never use before

Comment: Check out the Getting Started page. You can either import all of the components or only a handful. This would keep your package size more maintainable.

Comment: If you understand Angular Input/Output attributes, you won't have a hard time learning this. It's much easier than brute-forcing native bootstrap code on your application.